# PHP regex not producing desired result despite appearing to work OK in regex tester

Tags: php, regex

I've got a PHP search and replace regex that's giving me some trouble. I've used the regex tester at http://www.regextester.com/index2.html to test it as preg and it works there, but I can't seem to get the desired result within the PHP script I'm working on.

Here's the code for the regex:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^prescriptions-a-z\/prescriptions-([a-z]{1}-[a-z]{1})\/([-a-z0-9_]*)\.html$/', '$1 $2', $url);
```

The string in $url is

```
prescriptions-a-z/prescriptions-a-c/atopica-capsules.html
```

and the result should be

```
a-c atopica-capsules
```

However, it's returning an empty result. Can anyone throw any light on why this isn't producing the output I want?

Comment: Looks like it works as expected - http://codepad.viper-7.com/avGQP8 - double-check that $url contains what you expect, no trailing spaces or returns or case-differences

Comment: @Mark Baker Yes. When I manually define the $url variable it works fine - some earlier code strips away part of the URL so I'll see if it's added some whitespace or something. It shouldn't be a difference in case because earlier on I convert the whole string to lowercase anyway.

Comment: Please do a `var_dump()` of the actual string where the regex is failing, and edit your question to include the output.

Comment: @mattbd offtopic but you can use pattern '/..../i' (with i at the end) to ignore case.

Comment: @Pawka Yes, I'm aware of that. I actually convert the whole string to lower case earlier in the script so that shouldn't be an issue here, but normally I would use that

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem might actually be somewhere else other than the regex as it seems like it works fine from the command line if I define the URL manually. I shall go back to it. Cheers for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going back and looking at the code I've figured out what it was - turned out an earlier regex was wrong so the code wasn't executing in the first place. D'oh! It's now working fine though. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$url = 'prescriptions-a-z/prescriptions-a-c/atopica-capsules.html';
$result = preg_replace('/^prescriptions-a-z\/prescriptions-([a-z]{1}-[a-z]{1})\/([-a-z0-9_]*)\.html$/', '\\1 \\2', $url);
echo $result;
```

References use the `\\` character not the `$`, you can review the function [manual](http://fr.php.net/preg_replace)

Comment: Example 1 on the manual page that you link to uses $1 rather than \\1, both are valid

Comment: @MarkBaker: actually just test $ also works, are you sure it is not working?

Answer (score -2):

Your replace isn't correct

`'$1 $2'` should be `'\\1 \\2'`

Comment: Since when? I've been using `$` syntax for years. What is the difference?

Comment: @Richard - I have RTFM... please indicate exactly where on that page it says $1 is not acceptable usage, and then explain why Example 1 on that page uses $ rather than \\

Comment: @Richard I've read that manual page many, many times in the last 10 years, and skim read it again before asking my question. You're claiming that `'$1 $2'` is incorrect but `'\\1 \\2'` is correct. Can you please explain *why* one is incorrect and the other isn't? I thought they were both the same.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see anywhere where it says that the `$1` is **in**correct usage, but I also don't see where it says it is correct (exept for usage in examples). Either way, all should work: http://codepad.viper-7.com/CAQJqL